# Displaying the database table on the windows screen in real time

Tags: java, sql-server, real-time

I have a database table which is running on a remote host. I need to write a program to display this table in a windows form or on a html page on the desktop screen. The program needs to run at equal intervals (say 30 min).

After every 30 min the program will run and the data needs to be overridden on that form or page. There could be any approach to this. Prefer Java.

Comment: `It would be good if you can give the code for this.` I think a lot of people would be willing to do it for money. This is however a QA site, not a (free) coding service... [Please read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about what questions are welcome here on [SO]

Comment: Hey, stackoverflow would help if you are having a problem with your code. This community will not do the work for you. How about you start trying to figure it out, and ask specific questions when you are having problems.

Comment: ok...dnt give the code ...just tell how we can do this .

Answer (score 0):

Two different ways of doing it (really three, the third one being running a java-applet)

The coarsest way is to put a refresh header in your html like

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="600;URL=page.php">
```

where you have to exchange page.php with whatever is the address of the page you want to reload (this says basically after 600 secounds, load page "page.php" You will not be able to sync this to the dbupdates, as the refresh happens a fixed time after the page load. So how often you reload will be a compromise between your server load and how long delay you will accept. Also, you probably will want to have this as a separate frame (ooouch!) if some information is to be entered on the page.

A bit more contemporary, use javascript ajax and timed events. You want to juse jquery or prototype.js or another library for that. Here you may be able to sync the reloads to the database updates, given that the real time clock on the workstation and the server are in sync.

Comment: Unless the client always will be on the same network as the server, the easiest is probably to fetch the data using html.

Comment: I think it could be done using jsp but how will i make that program run periodically .Can i do this using task scheduler ,but i think the problem would be overriding of the data. In jsp also, will have to use jdbc ...right ?? see i am not much of a programmer...but i think by "fetching the data using html" u meant jsp ??

Comment: Sorry, now you are beyond my competence. I have written a couple of applets (one of them fetching data from the backend server using http... ) but I'm not that much into java programming.
You can use the timer class to run something periodcally (e.g. http://www.shanison.com/2010/05/18/how-to-use-java-timer-class/ ) Maybe the best way of doing it will be to run relatively often a query asking if there is something new, then you analyse the answer and fetch the data if there is something new .